# Merging two list into one with unique values

Tags: python, loops, python-logging

I am trying to merge two lists where the values differ by the last 3 digits.

Input list 1:

```
['YTS0R000', 'YTS1R000', 'YTS2R000']
```

Input list 2:

```
['YTS0R101', 'YTS5R101', 'YTS2R101']
```

Desired output:

```
['YTS0R000', 'YTS1R000', 'YTS5R101', 'YTSR000']
```

I've tried

```
for input in Final_1_out:
    for input2 in Final_1_in:
        if input[-3:]!=input2[-3:]:
            Final_in_out.append((input))
```

but I am getting duplicate entries

Comment: Please update your question containing the input data and the desired output.

Comment: input list 1 'YTS0R000','YTS1R000','YTS2R000'
Input List 2 'YTS0R101','YTS5R101,'YTS2R101'
OUTPUT: 'YTS0R000','YTS1R000','YTS5R101','YTS2R000'

Comment: Aside: Don't use `input` as a variable name, you're overriding a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the lists to a `dict` where the key is the string but the last 3 digits and the value is the string itself. And then use the union operator to merge them. Then, convert back to `list` using dict.values().

```py
merged_lists = list((
  {item[0:-3]:item for item in Final_1_in} |
  {item[0:-3]:item for item in Final_1_out}
).values())
```

Output:

```py
['YTS0R000', 'YTS5R101', 'YTS2R000', 'YTS1R000']
```

Comment: input list 1 'YTS0R000','YTS1R000','YTS2R000' Input List 2 'YTS0R101','YTS5R101,'YTS2R101' OUTPUT: 'YTS0R000','YTS1R000','YTS5R101','YTS2R000

Comment: I've edited the answer with a new solution given the output. It works if the output order doesn't matter.